# Ruby Mongoid: How to convert a date into age?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a date in Mongoid `user` collection field `dob`.
I want to get those users whose age is between 18-30.
but i don't know how to get age from date in Mongoid.
here is the query:

```
User.in(gender: gender_group).between(dob: 18..30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering a user is 30 years old if he has not yet celebrated his 31st birthday, following would be your logic:

```
today = Date.today
 => Mon, 07 May 2018

aged_30 = today - 31.years + 1.day
 => Fri, 08 May 1987

aged_18 = today - 18.years
 => Sun, 07 May 2000

User.in(gender: gender_group).between(dob: aged_30..aged_18)
```